# OpenCV Python VideoWriter saves corrupted video

Tags: python, opencv, save, video-processing

I am trying to get a very simple example of copying a video before I start modifying frames in the video. However, the output.avi video is a 5kb corrupted file compared to the 2.8 mb barriers.avi video. I am using OpenCV version 4.2.0 and Python version 3.7.7.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2

input = cv2.VideoCapture("../video/barriers.avi")
height = int(input.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
width = int(input.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('../video/output5.avi', fourcc, 30, (height, width), isColor=True)

while input.isOpened():
    # get validity boolean and current frame
    ret, frame = input.read()

    # if valid tag is false, loop back to start
    if not ret:
        break
    else:
        out.write(frame)

input.release()
out.release()
```

If I printed the frame shape, I get:

```
(480, 640, 3)
```

Note: None of the other stack overflow solutions have helped.

Edit: All frames display fine if cv2.imshow() is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to address two issues in your code:

---

***Issue#1:***: You want to create a `.avi` video file. Therefore you need to initialize your fourcc as `MJPG`:

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
```

There are certain combinations for creating a video file. For instance, if you want to create a `.mp4` you initialize your fourcc as `*'mp4v'`.

---

***Issue#2:*** Make sure the size of the output video is the same as the input frame. For instance: you declared your Videowriter object size `(height, width)`. Then your frame must be the same size:

```py
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (height, width))
```

---

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("output.mp4")
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output5.avi', fourcc, 30, (width, height), isColor=True)

while cap.isOpened():
    # get validity boolean and current frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # if valid tag is false, loop back to start
    if not ret:
        break
    else:
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height))
        out.write(frame)

cap.release()
out.release()
```

Comment: Thank you. This saves correctly for me. Only issue is the barriers.avi has video dimension (width=640, hieght=480) and the output.avi saves the file with dimension (width=480, height=640). And for resizing the frames, is this one the assumption that some frames are not all the same size? Or is this for rescaling if you want the output to be smaller?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake it should be `frame = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height))`

Comment: Actually, with that change, the video is corrupted again. Perhaps the video writer dimensions are flipped? Edit: that fix worked. the video writer dims should be (width, height) instead of (height, width). Thanks!

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem. The issue is when you are declaring the size, please use `(width, height)` but when you are getting the image size, for instance: `image.shape[:2]` returns height width. I've updated the code, please let me know if there is any problem.